# Can keyword "explicit" be removed from a constructor in one specific template instantiation?

Tags: c++, templates, explicit-conversion, template-classes

I'm trying to create a template class to enforce dimensional correctness (length divided by time gives speed, and so on).

**The short story:** "Dimensionless" is one of the possible instantiations.  It would be convenient if I could allow *all* instantiations to be explicitly constructed from doubles, and furthermore allow the "dimensionless" instantiation (and only the dimensionless instantiation) to be implicitly constructed from doubles.

**The long story:** My template class is laid out as

```
template<int iLength, int iTime, int iMass>
class qty {
   double data;

   //Operators overloaded to enforce dimensional correctness
   //  e.g. qty<a,b,c> can only be added to qty<a,b,c>
   //       qty<a,b,c> * qty<a2,b2,c2> returns qty<a+a2,b+b2,c+c2>

};
```

Following this style, `qty<0,0,0>` is a dimensionless quantity, so it should be possible to add or subtract a `qty<0,0,0>` and a double.  I've currently enforced this by *declaring*

```
    qty operator+ (const double& rhs) const;
```

...but only *defining* it for `qty<0,0,0>`.  This is workable... but I think I could do better.  If I allowed implicit conversion from a double to a `qty<0,0,0>`, then addition of a double and `qty<0,0,0>` wouldn't require special handling.  User mistakes would also give more suggestive error messages --- attempting to add a double to a speed would indicate that a conversion isn't possible (getting at the underlying idea of dimensional incompatibility) rather that complaining that the function isn't defined (which could lead users to suspect an error in the template class).

The problem is that I can't allow implicit construction for any other combination of template parameters.  If I did, then addition of any qty and a double would always succeed; I want to force the user to think about dimensional correctness, and explicitly convert double constants to the appropriate dimension before addition (if that's the intended operation). I do, however, want to allow *explicit* construction from doubles --- without it, the simple declaration

```
qty<1,-1,0> a(1.5); //speed with value 1.5
```

would need an awkward conversion function

```
qty<1,-1,0> a = makeQty<1,-1,0>( 1.5 ); //my eyes hurt
```

This means that what I really want is

```
template<int iLength, int iTime, int iMass>
class qty {
    double data;
    explicit qty(const double& rhs) : data(rhs) {} //general version prohibits
                                                   //implicit conversion

    //...
};

template<>       
qty<0,0,0>::qty(const double&rhs) : data(rhs) {} //Explicit instantiation
                                                 //for dimensionless case
        // ... with black magic to reallow implicit conversion 
        // for this instantiation only ???
```

As you can see, I'm unsure of whether it's possible to remove the `explicit` specification for one instantiation only, and --- if it is possible --- I'm not sure what the syntax is.

Comment: You cannot change a member declaration, but you can specialize the entire template for the case `qty<0,0,0>`.

Comment: Have you seen the [analog literals](http://www.eelis.net/C++/analogliterals.xhtml)?

Comment: Actually, you could just define two mutually-SFINAE-exclusive constructors.

Comment: @KerrekSB SFINAE will not work when it does not depend on a deduced type in the ctor.

Comment: @DanielFrey: Hm, at least you'd have to make the constructor into a template, too. But it's really not helping, you're right.

Comment: @KerrekSB Specializing the entire template would give the advantage of more meaningful error messages, but I don't think it would reduce the amount of code duplication, would it?

Comment: `qty<1,-1,0> a = makeQty<1,-1,0>( 1.5 ); //my eyes hurt` -- If your eyes hurt for that, then you haven't spent enough time in the C++ world. Also, you can use `auto`: `auto a = makeQty<1,-1,0>( 1.5 );`

Answer (score 1):

We create a type that is `T` or a type that you cannot create depending on a bool:

```
template<bool b, typename T>
struct block_unless {
  struct type { type() = delete; operator T(); }; // operator T is standard-paranoia
};
template<typename T>
struct block_unless<true, T> {
  using type = T;
};
template<bool b, typename T>
using block_unless_t = typename block_unless<b,T>::type;
template<bool b, typename T>
using block_if_t = block_unless_t<!b, T>;
```

Then we guard the methods that we want blocked/activated inline with the rest of the code:

```
template<int a, int b, int c>
struct qty {
  enum { scalar = (a==0)&&(b==0)&&(c==0) };
  explict qty( block_if_t< scalar, double > d );
  qty( block_unless_t< scalar, double > d );
};
```

how about that?

In C++1y, requires clauses will probably do a better job.

(The standard paranoia is because of the verbage in the standard where a template method has to have at least one valid instantiation: while unreachable, `operator T` means that your code working with `d` will work in 99% of contexts where the code expects a `double`.)

Comment: If I understand this correctly, then `qty<0,0,0>` has an explicit constructor from `block_unless<false,double>::type` (which can't ever be called because this type has no constructor) and an implicit constructor from `double`, and the implicit/explicit classification is reversed for all other instantiations. Cool! Can you expand on the last paragraph? Which template method would not have a valid instantiation without `operator T`, and what's the 1-in-100 instance where this won't work?

Comment: @user1476176 There is an obscure paragraph in the standard that states that a `template` function must have at least one specialization for which instantiation is valid, and if that fails, the program is ill-formed with no diagnostic required.  I suspect this is to leave open the possibility for **more** checks on the validity of `template` code in the future without breaking conforming previous version C++ code.  The cast-to-`T` is an attempt to make this less likely: and it probably does not apply anyhow.  It is highly academic, because no production compiler ever enforces that obscure rule.

Comment: @user1476176 A case where the `operator T` is technically insufficient might be where the body of a blocked `template` method has a function that takes a type `U` and only compiles if `U` is a `double`: we convert to `double` implicitly, we are not a `double`.  There are going to be others.  Again, this is just academic.

Answer (score 0):

You can not change it directly, but the following will work with C++11:

```
template<int iLength, int iTime, int iMass>
class qty_impl {
    double data;
public:
    explicit qty_impl(const double& rhs) : data(rhs) {} //general version prohibits
                                                        //implicit conversion

    //...
};

// general case: simply forward to _impl
template<int iLength, int iTime, int iMass>
class qty : public qty_impl<iLength,iTime,iMass> {
    // inherit ctors, including "explicit"
    using qty_impl<iLength,iTime,iMass>::qty_impl;
};

// special case
template<>
class qty<0,0,0> : public qty_impl<0,0,0> {
    using qty_impl<0,0,0>::qty_impl;
public:
    // provide non-explicit ctor to override the inherited base ctors
    qty(const double& rhs) : qty_impl<0,0,0>(rhs) {}
};
```

That allows you to keep a common implementation for almost everything and simply forward the non-explicit ctor to the explicit one.

Comment: I like this.  I gave it a try, but now all my operators return type qty_impl, so writing qty = (operation returning qty_impl) is a compile error.  Can this be circumvented? I tried writing a constructor for qty accepting a qty_impl, but it didn't seem to fix things...

Comment: @user1476176 You might try a CRTP variant and pass in `qty` as a template parameter to `qty_impl` and use it to implement the operators.